# Have error when try to change permission

Tags: access

please help. When I tried to change permission thru Administer -> users and permissions -> Permissions (access control), I have the  following error.

Exception: "API error: 'search_display_type' is not a valid option for field option_group_id on OptionValue.create( entity name crm-search-display-table)"

#0 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php(249): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->onApiError()
#1 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php(144): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->updateExistingEntity()
#2 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/ManagedEntities.php(112): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->reconcileEntities()
#3 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(417): CRM_Core_ManagedEntities->reconcile()
#4 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/ACL/Form/WordPress/Permissions.php(184): CRM_Core_Invoke::rebuildMenuAndCaches()
#5 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Form.php(573): CRM_ACL_Form_WordPress_Permissions->postProcess()
#6 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/StateMachine.php(144): CRM_Core_Form->mainProcess()
#7 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/QuickForm/Action/Next.php(43): CRM_Core_StateMachine->perform()
#8 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Controller.php(203): CRM_Core_QuickForm_Action_Next->perform()
#9 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/packages/HTML/QuickForm/Page.php(103): HTML_QuickForm_Controller->handle()
#10 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Controller.php(355): HTML_QuickForm_Page->handle()
#11 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Utils/Wrapper.php(98): CRM_Core_Controller->run()
#12 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(292): CRM_Utils_Wrapper->run()
#13 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(69): CRM_Core_Invoke::runItem()
#14 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Invoke.php(36): CRM_Core_Invoke::_invoke()
#15 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm.php(1199): CRM_Core_Invoke::invoke()
#16 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(308): CiviCRM_For_WordPress->invoke()
#17 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(332): WP_Hook->apply_filters()
#18 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action()
#19 /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-admin/admin.php(259): do_action()
#20 {main}
Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
API error: 'search_display_type' is not a valid option for field option_group_id on OptionValue.create( entity name crm-search-display-table)
Return to home page.

Comment: Be sure you have the Search Kit extension enabled.